# Realm query for array of compound filters

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to query all the products with multiple filters, e.g.:

All products with: `[(name: "cookies", brand: "brand x"), (name: "water", brand: "brand y")]`

If I had only one filter, e.g. `(name: "cookies", brand: "brand x")` the answer would be clear: `name == \(tuple.name) AND brand == \(tuple.brand)`

If I have multiple tuples but with only one property, it wold also be clear:

```
return "name IN {\(["cookies", "water"].joined(separator: ","))}"
```

But how do I write the filter for my array of tuples? An idea would be to fetch each as single `Results` using the former query `name == \(tuple.name) AND brand == \(tuple.brand)`, and build an array with this, but I need the end result in `Results` not an array.

Also something like this maybe but I think this is not possible?

```
return "name::brand IN {\(["cookies::brand x", "water::brand y"].joined(separator: ","))}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you want to combine predicates together with [`NSCompoundPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscompoundpredicate):

```
class Product: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var brand = ""
}

let productsFilter: [(name: String, brand: String)] = [("cookies", "brand x"), ("water", "brand y")]
let subPredicates = productsFilter.map {
    NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ && brand = %@", $0.name, $0.brand)
}
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)

let realm = try Realm()
let products = realm.objects(Product.self).filter(compoundPredicate)
```